# plasma visual feedback indicators have stopped working in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma, latte-dock

Currently my Fn shortcuts work, but they do not trigger any indicator pop up on the screen. I have tried checking/unchecking the: System Settings > Workspace Behaviour > General Behavriour > "Display visual feedback for status changes", but it does not have any effect on the situation.

I have also reset the theme I was using to KDE Breeze, and can confirm it does not have any effect whatsoever.

The only temporary solution seems to be removing the "Audio Volume" panel from Latte Dock and adding it again, which only solves the issue till the next reboot. And when the system restarts, it reverts to no visual feedback situation again.